# How to sort in dates in linux based on day, date, month, and year

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, rpm, sort

I am trying to sort dates (like in the format below) and cannot get them in order based on the day, date, month, and year.  I have tried a few different ways and have come up short.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

What Ive tried:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{installtime:date}\n' | 
    sort -n
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{installtime:date}\n' | 
    awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | sort -t- -k2.1,2.3
rpm -qa --queryformat '%{installtime:date}\n' | 
    awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | sort -n -k3 -k2 -k1
```

Format/Output:

```
Wed 17 May 2017 01:41:05 PM CDT
Wed 17 May 2017 01:41:05 PM CDT
Wed 17 May 2017 01:41:06 PM CDT
Wed 17 May 2017 01:41:06 PM CDT
Wed 28 Apr 2021 08:56:30 AM CDT
Wed 29 Jan 2020 04:57:23 PM CST
Wed 29 Jan 2020 04:57:24 PM CST
```

Comment: Are you trying to get sorted dates (as the current output demonstrates) or are you really trying to get the list of packages in order of their installed date?

Answer (score 3):

Use `sort`'s `-M` option to order months in the "Jan".."Dec" order:

```
 sort -k4,4n -k3,3M -k2,2n
```

will order your output by year, then month and lastly the day of the month.

The key specification form of `-k field1[,field2]` can be very important (though not so much in this example). If `field2` is missing for a key, the end of the key defaults to the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
$ rpm -qa --last --queryformat '%{installtime:date}\n'
```

or maybe:

```
$ rpm -qa --last --queryformat '%{installtime:date}\n' | tac
```

to list them in the inverse order

Answer (score 1):

You can convert dates with `date` (look at `man date`) using

```
"%s     seconds since the Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00 UTC)"
```

eg

```
]$ date -d "Wed 17 May 2017 01:41:05 PM CDT" +%s
1495046465
```

then use `sort` on theses then convert back dates

```
date -d @1495046465
```

You may have to use TZ (`man date` again)